# How to Filter array from state onChange based on category and revert to default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

For my class based component, I have a `state` **object** that contains a defined array named `movies`. I also have a `handleMoviesFilter` function, that is called `onChange` on the `select` tag.

How can I filter the options dynamically from my array, filter them onChange.. and revert when I pick another movie?

```
state = {
    movies: [
        {
            name: 'Goodfellas',
            category: 'crime'
        },

        {
            name: 'Saving private ryan',
            category: 'war'
        },
        {
            name: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
            category: 'drama'
        }
    ]
}

handleMoviesFilter = e => {
    let currentMovie = e.target.value;

    const updateMoviesState = this.state.movies.filter(({ category }) =>
        currentMovie.includes(category)
    );

    this.setState({
        opleidingen: updateMoviesState,
        isResetButtonActive: true,
    });
}

<select id="lang" onChange={this.handleMoviesFilter}>
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    <option value="Goodfellas">Goodfellas</option>
    <option value="Saving private ryan">Saving private ryan</option>
    <option value="The Shawshank Redemption">The Shawshank Redemption</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Inside `handleMoviesFilter`, `currentMovie` is just a string (e.g. `GoodFellas`).  What are you expecting to happen when you're filtering `this.state.movies`?

Comment: when a `<option>` is selected, what are you trying to do with the contents inside `<select>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are trying to accomplish is based upon the selected option, filter the state.movies and return those in which match, then you would want to do something like the following...

```
state = {
    movies: [
        {
            name: 'Goodfellas',
            category: 'crime'
        },

        {
            name: 'Saving private ryan',
            category: 'war'
        },
        {
            name: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
            category: 'drama'
        }
    ]
}

handleMoviesFilter = e => {
    let currentMovie = e.target.value;

    const updateMoviesState = this.state.movies.filter(movie => movie.name.toLowerCase() === currentMovie.toLowerCase());

    this.setState({
        movies: updateMoviesState,
        isResetButtonActive: true,
    });
}

<select id="lang" onChange={this.handleMoviesFilter}>
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    <option value="Goodfellas">Goodfellas</option>
    <option value="Saving private ryan">Saving private ryan</option>
    <option value="The Shawshank Redemption">The Shawshank Redemption</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works but it destroys my original array from 28 items after filtering i get 10.. and i am not able to revert back to the original state. How can i keep the original array?

Comment: @Galanthus, Something that I would do is have an array that is responsible for showing the filtered items, and one array that contains all of the items. This is often a pattern that I use.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to

- get the selected value
- **uppercase** all of it's characters with `toUpperCase()`
- **filter** `state` to get the movies that **includes** the selected value in it's **name**

  - filter & includes method used

```
state = {
    movies: [
        {
            name: 'Goodfellas',
            category: 'crime'
        },

        {
            name: 'Saving private ryan',
            category: 'war'
        },
        {
            name: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
            category: 'drama'
        },
        {
            name: 'Good Riddance',
            category: 'drama'
        }
    ]
}

handleMoviesFilter = e => {
    let currentMovie = e.target.value.toUpperCase();


    //const updateMoviesState = this.state.movies.filter(movie => movie.name.toUpperCase() === currentMovie);

    const updateMoviesState = this.state.movies.filter(movie => movie.name.toUpperCase().includes(currentMovie));
    this.setState({
        movies: updateMoviesState,
        isResetButtonActive: true,
    });
}

<select id="lang" onChange={this.handleMoviesFilter}>
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    <option value="Goodfellas">Goodfellas</option>
    <option value="Saving private ryan">Saving private ryan</option>
    <option value="The Shawshank Redemption">The Shawshank Redemption</option>
</select>
```

## Test It Out

*This snippet was made so you can test it out. **This does NOT include react-js framework of course***.

```js
const state = {
    movies: [
        {
            name: 'Goodfellas',
            category: 'crime'
        },

        {
            name: 'Saving private ryan',
            category: 'war'
        },
        {
            name: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
            category: 'drama'
        },
        {
            name: 'Good Riddance',
            category: 'drama'
        }
    ]
}

handleMoviesFilter = e => {
    // get requested movie
    let currentMovie = document.getElementById('textField').value.toUpperCase(); // t
    console.log("Requested Movie:", currentMovie);
    
    // array has a movie that equals selected movie
    //const updateMoviesState = state.movies.filter(movie => movie.name.toUpperCase() === currentMovie);

    // array has a movie whose name contain the phrase 
    const updateMoviesState = state.movies.filter(movie => movie.name.toUpperCase().includes(currentMovie));

    console.log("Filter Result:", updateMoviesState);
}
```

```html
<input id="textField"></input>
<button onclick="handleMoviesFilter(event)">Filter</button>
```